# Getting file name from body parser

Tags: express, multer, body-parser

Can I get the  name from body parser from multipart form post?

Using Multer, I can get the files uploaded, but I just want the name?

Use hidden file? but how? I am using Jasny Boostrap for file field.

Comment: Express body-parser module (https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) does not handle anymore multipart uploads, so you cannot get file name. Why cannot you just use multer for that?